# Conditional update on MySQL db based on whether a column value has reached a final state, eg -1

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have a table that contains three columns - ID, Name, Status. Status can be any of -1, 0, 1, 2. Initial value will always be 0 and on update it can be 1, 2 or -1. Is it possible for me to define a constraint that if ever the value for Status sets to -1, it can never get updated from that state. Hence if an update statement happens where the old value for Status = -1 and the new value for Status is 2, it should fail and not overwrite Status = -1 with Status = 2.

Is it possible to do that on a ORM level/MySQL db level/any other means in Java

Lets assume its a valid usecase.

Comment: Somebody already answered but I will add that if you also want to validate on the entity side, you could use `@PreUpdate`: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [BEFORE UPDATE trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) that prevents the row from being updated if the current value of `Status` is `-1`:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trg_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
ON tablename FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.Status = -1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The row can''t be updated because the status is -1';
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Change `tablename` to the name of your table.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f2f1df9c10590201cf8fcdae2f919c38).